# Linking (Loading?) error with QT application

Tags: c++, qt

After compiling a sample QT-based application that is using a graphing library, I get this error when I attempt to run the application:

```
./basic_dyn 
./basic_dyn: symbol lookup error: /qanava-0.4/lib/libqanava.so.0.4.0: undefined symbol: _ZNK18QAbstractListModel7siblingEiiRK11QModelIndex
```

In the past, I've seen these errors coming from failing to link in an appropriate library.  So seeing as how the error is coming from the graphing library, I did a quick check on the names from the library:

```
nm libqanava.so.0.4.0 | grep QAbstractListModel
    U _ZN18QAbstractListModel11qt_metacallEN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv
    U _ZN18QAbstractListModel11qt_metacastEPKc
    [[ .... several list of output removed ....]]
    U _ZNK18QAbstractListModel6parentERK11QModelIndex
    U _ZNK18QAbstractListModel7siblingEiiRK11QModelIndex
    U _ZTI18QAbstractListModel
```

From which we can see that the offending function (`_ZNK18QAbstractListModel7siblingEiiRK11QModelIndex`) is indeed present in the library.  Repeating the name extraction, and this time turning name demangling on, gives;

```
nm -C libqanava.so.0.4.0 | grep QAbstractListModel
    U QAbstractListModel::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
    U QAbstractListModel::qt_metacast(char const*)
    [[ .... several lines removed .... ]]
    U QAbstractListModel::parent(QModelIndex const&) const
    U QAbstractListModel::sibling(int, int, QModelIndex const&) const
    U typeinfo for QAbstractListModel
```

SO, we can see that the function is `QAbstractListModel::sibling`.  Referring to the QT documentation, it appears that this class is part of the Qt5Core library.  In fact looking at the exported functions from Qt5Core, we find:

```
nm -C libQt5Core.so.5.5.1 | grep QAbstractListModel
  0000000000503a40 r qt_meta_data_QAbstractListModel
     [[ .... many lines deleted .... ]]
  00000000002257c0 T QAbstractListModel::parent(QModelIndex const&) const
  00000000002257f0 T QAbstractListModel::sibling(int, int, QModelIndex const&) const
  000000000059f850 V typeinfo for QAbstractListModel
```

So the offening function is being exported from Qt5Core.  And, I would expect the symbol to be defined.

The application is compiled as, and we can see that libQt5Core is being linked in:

```
g++ moc_canMainWindow.o canApp.o canMainWindow.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/opt /qt5/lib 
-L../../lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Xml -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets -lqanava -lpng -lfreetype -lSM 
-lICE   -lXext -lX11  -lz -lm -pthread  -lrt -ldl -o basic_dyn
```

so, the appropriate QT-libraries are on the command line, and I would have expected that the symbols would have been resolved.  Changing the order of the libraries on the command line (changed to `-lqanava -lQt5Gui -lQt5Xml -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets`) has no effect on the outcome.

I am at a loss, from what I understand, I would expect the symbols to be resolved and the application would run.  Anyone have a explanation of what is going on here, and a suggest of how to fix this>

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I've got the exact same symbol lookup error running application named qDslrDashboard. In case you got a solution, please post it. Thanks.

Comment: @snahl I believe that this came about due to having two versions of QT on the system, I had the version I built from source in /opt/qt5 (which was version qt-5.5.1) and I also had  version 4.8.6 installed with the system.  Everything build fine (as I was giving complete paths to the headers and libraries to use.  However during execution, it would default to the system version.    As I recall, adding `-Wl,-rpath,$(QTHOME)/lib` to the linker command solved the problem.  You can check with LDD to see which versions of the library you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I saw your reply only after I posted my quasi solution. I am on qt-5.5.1 too, and Raspian OS. I certainly try your much better answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will not be too happy because I am not able to give you a concise answer, but I had the exact same error, in fact your error-msg was my search term (=undefined symbol: _ZNK18QAbstractListModel7siblingEiiRK11QModelIndex). That's how I got here.
Hence it might be that my 'solution' gives you a hint towards the solution of your problem.

After a lot of tedious trail-and-error I realized that the CPU/GPU went up in utilization immediately before this error would occur. Stress & Overload, it seems to be the cause. Therefore I scaled down the screen resolution and provided the GPU more RAM (this is on a Raspberry Pi 2). Et voilà this error vanished.
In other words, I packed the mule until it could go any further. Solution: less load. Hope that makes sense somehow and brings you closer to a solution.
Greetings.